# Doctrine Collection Json Response Issue

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

So, i have and Ajax POST who call a function in the controller that retunrn a json response like this:

```
    $images = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Image')->findBy(array(),array(),5);
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(array(
        'images' => $images
    ));
    return $response;
```

I get the five elements, but there are all empty... like in the image below:

[image: array]

For example, i return some property from the elements i the array and it works:

```
$images = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Image')->findBy(array(),array(),5);
$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData(array(
   'images' => $images[0]->getSlug()
));

return $response;
```

[image: success]

This is the simple ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
     method: 'POST',
     url: $("#scroll-down").attr("data-href"),
     success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
     },
     error: function() {
          console.log(response);
     }
}).fail(function() {
     console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Symfony `JsonResponse` is mainly a wrapper for php function `json_encode`

`json_encode` will not encode private object properties.

```
<?php

class Test {
    private $a = null;
    public $b = 3;

    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

$test = new Test(1);

echo json_encode($test);
```

This will output `{"b":3}` because `$a` is private

So you should use the second form on your question or use a serializer bundle

Comment: Right, the Doctrine ArrayColelction has a private attribute called $elemnts. The solution could be using a proper library for serializing objects, like jms_serializer. This library use the reflection, then also the private methods will be serialized!